# Get Active Directory Username in SharePoint2013

Tags: active-directory

I want to get the Active Directory username from SharePoint page. I will send it to a page on another server. How can I do this?

My page's Code:

```
 <%-- _lcid="1033" _version="15.0.4420" _dal="1" --%>
<%-- _LocalBinding --%>
<%@ Page language="C#" MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master"    Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage,Microsoft.SharePoint,Version=15.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" meta:webpartpageexpansion="full" meta:progid="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document"  %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %> <%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:ListItemProperty Property="BaseName" maxlength="40" runat="server"/>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
    <meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft SharePoint" />
    <meta name="ProgId" content="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="CollaborationServer" content="SharePoint Team Web Site" />
    <SharePoint:ScriptBlock runat="server">
    var navBarHelpOverrideKey = &quot;WSSEndUser&quot;;
    </SharePoint:ScriptBlock>
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="core.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false" />
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="menu.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false" />
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="callout.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false" />
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="sharing.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false" />
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="suitelinks.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false" />
    <SharePoint:CustomJSUrl runat="server" />

<SharePoint:StyleBlock runat="server">
body #s4-leftpanel {
    display:none;
}
.s4-ca {
    margin-left:0px;
}
</SharePoint:StyleBlock>
<script type="text/javascript">


  $(document).ready(function () {

       string strUserName = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName;
       alert(strUserName);



});

</script>

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderSearchArea" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server"
        ControlId="SmallSearchInputBox"/>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageDescription" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:ProjectProperty Property="Description" runat="server"/>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
  <div class="ms-hide">
    <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" title="loc:TitleBar" id="TitleBar" AllowLayoutChange="false" AllowPersonalization="false" Style="display:none;"><ZoneTemplate><WebPartPages:TitleBarWebPart runat="server" HeaderTitle="Untitled_1" Title="Web Part Page Title Bar" FrameType="None" SuppressWebPartChrome="False" Description="" IsIncluded="True" ZoneID="TitleBar" PartOrder="1" FrameState="Normal" AllowRemove="False" AllowZoneChange="True" AllowMinimize="False" AllowConnect="True" AllowEdit="True" AllowHide="True" IsVisible="True" DetailLink="" HelpLink="" HelpMode="Modeless" Dir="Default" PartImageSmall="" MissingAssembly="Cannot import this Web Part." PartImageLarge="" IsIncludedFilter="" ExportControlledProperties="True" ConnectionID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" ID="g_022a1f1a_a95c_4033_92fe_2d39224dc497" AllowClose="False" ChromeType="None" ExportMode="All" __MarkupType="vsattributemarkup" __WebPartId="{022A1F1A-A95C-4033-92FE-2D39224DC497}" WebPart="true" Height="" Width=""></WebPartPages:TitleBarWebPart>

    </ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
  </div>
  <table class="ms-core-tableNoSpace ms-webpartPage-root" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td id="_invisibleIfEmpty" name="_invisibleIfEmpty" valign="top" width="100%"> 
                    <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" Title="loc:FullPage" ID="FullPage" FrameType="TitleBarOnly"><ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone> </td>
                </tr>
                <SharePoint:ScriptBlock runat="server">if(typeof(MSOLayout_MakeInvisibleIfEmpty) == &quot;function&quot;) {MSOLayout_MakeInvisibleIfEmpty();}</SharePoint:ScriptBlock>
        </table>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1):

To get username or login name using SSOM is very simple

```
string strUserName = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName;
```

To get username from CSOM

```
function getCurrentUser() {  
  var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  var web = context.get_web();  
  var currentUser = web.get_currentUser();  
  context.load(currentUser);  
  context.executeQueryAsync(onSuccessMethod, onRequestFail);  
}
```

You can use this query string to pass username to another URL.Make sure it is encrypted before passing in url

Comment: I added my page's code. I added your answer in document.ready(function). But I can't see username.  Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: @zengel You've mixed server side code with JS. I recomend CSOM or REST approach. If you really want to use server side code, use asp literal to render the value in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this URL using REST:

```
/_api/Web/currentUser/loginName
```

Note that it won't be AD user login, but SharePoint user login. For AD users it will be prefixed with `i:0#.w|`

In Office365 it's also stored in global js object. Possibly will be introduced to on prem version in future CU:

```
_spPageContextInfo.userLoginName
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the username from currently logged-In AD user, use below code:

```
string strUserName = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName.Replace("\\", ",").Split(',')[1].ToUpper();
```